# Task deletes with Opportunity with Opp deleted? (Parent/Grandparent relationship?)

Tags: opportunity, account, tasks

I'd appreciate it if someone "in the know" could verify this and let me know if there is a way to RECTIFY this.

1. A lead is created.  A task is linked to that Lead.
2. The lead is converted to an Account with Opportunity.  The task is linked to the Opportunity and Account (apparently the Opp is the parent and the Account is "only" the grandparent).
3. The Opp is DELETED.  The Task ends up deleted WITH the Opp.

This is not ideal in our scenario.  We would like to KEEP the Task when the Opp is deleted.  Is there a canned mechanism that handles such needs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism that addresses this. You will need to create a trigger on delete on Opportunity that checks if that opportunity has related tasks and re-parents them to the account. The following helper method should work for you:

```
public static void ReparentTasks(Map<Id, Opportunity> mapNew)
{
    for(list<Task> tasks : [select Id, whatID from Task where whatId in :mapNew.keyset()])
    {
        for(Task t : tasks) t.whatID = mapNew.get(t.WhatID).AccountID;
        update tasks;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up looks like update statement is in for loop.So may be declaring a list and moving update out of for loop will make solution robust!

Comment: That was intentional. There could be many tasks relating to opportunities so I'm using the query/querymore pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a trigger on Task object so that when a task is initially created , it will automatically be attached to related Account.